# JSON Decode Error:Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: json, django, api

I am running a admin website using Django. Trying to login my admin site and i am getting JSON Decode error.The response i am getting is 404 server error. Can anyone help to get out of this?

Here is my views.py:

```
def user_login(request):
datas= {'log':False}
if request.method == "POST":
    usern=request.POST.get('Username')
    print(usern)
    passw=request.POST.get('password')
    print(passw)
    response = requests.post(url='http://www.onebookingsystem.com/productionApi/API/Admin/login.php',data={"Username":usern,"password":passw})
    print(response)
    json_data = response.json()
    print(json_data)
    if json_data['status'] == 1:
        user=authenticate(Username=usern,password=passw)
        login(request,user)
        range_yearly = 0
        range_monthly = 0
        respo = requests.get(url='http://www.onebookingsystem.com/productionApi/API/Admin/admin_dashboard.php')
        data_dash = json.loads(respo.text)
```

The error i am getting is:

```
<Response [404]>
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Android V\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\cor
e\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\Android V\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\cor
e\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Android V\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\cor
e\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Android V\admin\obs_app\views.py", line 20, in user_login
    json_data = response.json()
  File "C:\Users\Android V\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\requests\m
odels.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Android V\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\lib\json\__init__.py", line
354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Android V\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\lib\json\decoder.py", line 3
39, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Android V\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\lib\json\decoder.py", line 3
57, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
[02/Nov/2019 10:51:12] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 89429
```

Answer (score 2):

i think it can help you:
first import json that is one of python built-in libraries.
then using this library, convert the response of your request to the json object using below syntax:

```
    import json

    json_data = json.loads(response)
```